# wifi at home does not work when the virtual machine is started

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vmware

I was using my virtual machine normally, but I did something to network settings and it is block my Wi-Fi when started up. I have a VMnet8 which equals to NAT. But when I am connecting it to Vmnet 8 virtual machine has not internet. With NAT it is same problem. That is why I used bridged. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the bridged connection, shut down the guest, go to setting for Network and uncheck "Replicate physical state" . Restart the test.

Also use the VMware Network editor to reset the NAT network (internal DHCP). You need to restart the machine after this.

Do the above, restart, make sure Wi-Fi is working, start the Guest and test.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention. It worked. I restored to defaults from virtual network editor and it worked properly.

Comment: You are very welcome. Happy to help